# Elasticsearch bulk no longer indexing docs, but no errors

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert

6.0

Hi running ES 1.6.0

I had a bulk indexing job that used to work fine. I wanted to bulk index a few more documents in a new index. I sent about 100K+ documents but only a few thousand got indexed.

I check the logs and there was no particular errors logged on the ES nodes and my JAVA client is not returning any errors.

I also looked at Marvel Bulk Thread Pool there was no rejections. The queue size was 0.

I have 20TB of disk space of which 13TB is used by other indexes. So I am below the disk watermark anything else?

Here is the bulking code...

```
        BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
        final Context ctx = getVertx().currentContext();

        for(int i = 0; i < documents.size(); i++)
        {   
            final JsonObject obj = documents.get(i);
            final JsonObject indexable = new JsonObject()

            .putString("action", "index")
            .putString("_index", obj.getString("index"))
            .putString("_type", obj.getString("type"))
            .putString("_id", obj.getString("id"))
            .putString("_route", obj.getString("routing"))
            .putObject("_source", obj);                                     

            final String index = getRequiredIndex(indexable, message);
            if (index == null) {
                return;
            }

            // type is optional
            String type = indexable.getString(CONST_TYPE);
            ;

            JsonObject source = indexable.getObject(CONST_SOURCE);
            if (source == null) {
                sendError(message, CONST_SOURCE + " is required");
                return;
            }

            // id is optional
            String id = indexable.getString(CONST_ID);
            String route = indexable.getString(CONST_ROUTE);

            IndexRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareIndex(index, type, id).setSource(source.encode());

            if(!route.isEmpty())
                builder.setRouting(route);              

            bulkRequest.add(builder);
        }

        bulkRequest.execute(new ActionListener<BulkResponse>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(BulkResponse resp) {


                message.reply(new JsonObject().putString("status", "Took: " + resp.getTookInMillis() + ", Indexed:" + documents.size() + "," + resp.getItems().length + ", Failed: " + resp.hasFailures()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                ctx.runOnContext(new Handler<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Void event) {
                        sendError(message,
                                "Index error: " + t.getMessage(),
                                new RuntimeException(t));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you, somehow, share the complete log file?

Comment: Ok let me run the process again. And see what I can put on drop box.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/boauxml5j2zn7nm/AABavysHdnbyTQPHx6yBewOYa?dl=0

I rebooted one node to mark a clean event. You will se there's no errors. Also added screen shot of marvel for last hour.

You can see outpu of my job file I have done more then a few thousands records. and it's based on the code posted above. hasFailures() returns false.

Comment: I just noticed something peculiar in Marvel. Marvel on the main page is reporting 3000 indexing requests/sec. Bulk Thread pools are not showing any rejections. But In Indices Store Delete Docuements I'm getting as many deleteions as documents indexed. Is ES eviciting my documents?

Comment: Hm, maybe your bulks are updates and not indexing request.

Comment: Hummmmm good point. There's no way to check that? I'll check my bulk index logic. I'm pretty sure it's an index operation, but indexing with same id causes an update right? Ok I need to investigate if for some reason I'm reusing ids.

Comment: If you are reusing IDs then it's update, meaning delete and insert.

Comment: Yep! My stupidity! Nothing to see here lol I mistakenly had ticked something in my Jmeter script that caused the ids to regenerate per user! Oops!